# Trigonometric functions not always exact in Excel

Tags: excel, trigonometry

I need to convert values between formats used by different applications, and one of the applications performs calculations in degrees, not radians.

Thus, the application always expects `cos(90)` to equal exactly `0`.

But in Excel, there are rounding errors when I do `cos(radians(90))`.

How do I handle situations like this?

Comment: Use `ROUND` perhaps.

Comment: It depends on the situation, your application and specific formulas and usages.  All real-valued computation involves some limitations on accuracy and some progressive loss of accuracy.  There's no silver bullet or universal cure for this, you have to look at the specifics, determine acceptable error ranges and then apply numerical techniques (and possibly even algorithms) to get within those ranges.  For instance, ROUND() alone might be sufficient for you in your situation.  Or it might not be, we'd have to know a lot more specifics to be able to figure that out.

Comment: afaik, excel only calculates at 32 digit accuracy.. since `PI()` have limited accuracy, I doubt `RADIANS()` will work with more precision. solution  (for conversion) : I use wolframalpha.com , or use Sagemath/Matlab/Mathematica for exact (symbolic) conversion.